# IAR skipping linking phase

Tags: c, linker, iar

I'm trying to run one of my work project in IAR IDE and it seems he compile all the files (i can see it in the build window) but never reach the Linking phase and the post-build action. (There is no line indicate he done anything).
In my boss PC it work 100% and preform all the require operations and no one know why...
we are using IAR 4.41A (and we are not allowed to upgrade)

Comment: Are you building the same code? Is the entire project in version control, and you both have identical copies? Or have you just been copying files around?

Comment: @pmacfarlane
Of course, the code is identical and is under version control. It may be somewhat related to the SW settings, in my opinion.

Comment: I would start by 1) validating the PC system requirements for the compiler version you are using and 2) then check if the compiler/linker is working from the command line, in order to make sure compiler got the license. Yet so it is a very dated compiler and you could have hit some critical bug.

Comment: hi @sharpgeek, thx for your response. 1) I already have compared the IAR 4.41A system requirements and my PC can run them pretty easily. 2) I just did it and using the iarbuild command from command prompt and its only compile the project. please let me know if you have any more ideas!

Comment: hi @BarBenezri. I think iarbuild might hide information from you, which is provided by the actual underlying tools. I'd suggest one additional test you might want to perform: invoking **iccarm** and **ilinkarm** directly on both machines. If it is a license error, the compiler/linker responses will probably differ on both PCs. On a second step, perhaps trying to compile and link a very simple "hello" executable (example: `void main(void) { while(1); }`) might also reveal more issues.

Comment: In summary, dividing to conquer might be helpful here: try to narrow down to the lowest common denominator until you make sure the compiler/linker is working and then, once you pinpoint the culprit, it might become easier for going back up in the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would inspect what the compiler/... is actually doing under the hood:

I use a newer (but similarly outdated) v7 IAR, and in that you can tell the IDE to print more output about what it is doing -- compiler flags being used etc.

In v7, you go to Tools->Options->Messages and select "Show Build Messages: **All**". In that same window you can also define a .log file where that output is dumped, so you can inspect it more conveniently than in the IDE console window.

I suspect IAR v4 will have a similar setting?